# Plotting with Maxima and Pango error

Tags: macos, plot, maxima

I've been running Maxima on my iMac with Sierra. I just tried doing some examples to learn about plotting. When I try to make a plot with the plot2d command I get my plot but there are no labels, no numbers on my axis and no title. No text at all. I also get a series of error messages related to a module called Pango.

The error messages are:

(process:11388): Pango-CRITICAL **: No modules found:
No builtin or dynamically loaded modules were found.
PangoFc will not work correctly.
This probably means there was an error in the creation of:
 '/opt/mac/quartz-new/etc/pango/pango.modules'
You should create this file by running:
 pango-querymodules > '/opt/mac/quartz-new/etc/pango/pango.modules'
(process:11388): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderCoreText', script='common'
(process:11388): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderCoreText', script='latin'

Does anyone know how to resolve this. It only happens with inline plots. If I use the wxmaxima menu for plotting and send it thru GNUPLOT I avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac so I haven't tried these commands; I found this info via a web search. I hope it works for you.

It appears that the Pango library is not installed. Searching the web seems to show that installing it is simple: http://brewformulas.org/Pango

That method requires a package manager named Homebrew. If that is not already installed, you'll need to install Homebrew first and then Pango. See: http://macappstore.org/pango/

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that tonight. I have Homebrew installed!

Comment: I tried this but kept getting message that it couldn't write to /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig directory. I tried changing write privilege but it still didn't work with same error message.

Comment: Well I tried the full command and it worked - for installing pango. But my plots generate same messages.  Thank you anyway. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: You might be able to get more help on the wxMaxima issues tracker: https://github.com/andrejv/wxmaxima/issues

Comment: Thank you. I posted my question there.